# Trace Error in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

I am creating my first MVC application with VS 2012 on WIN 10. I added this line in System.Web section of Web.config file:

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="True" />
```

My machine.config file has this line:

```
<section name="trace" type="System.Web.Configuration.TraceSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

and this line:

```
<section name="deployment" type="System.Web.Configuration.DeploymentSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineOnly"/>
```

When I run my application and enter this URL:http://localhost/MvcDemo/Trace.axd, I get the following error:
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'm not seeing the code you have in web.config or machine.config. Can you edit the question to add it? Perhaps you didn't indent each line 4 spaces to show it as code. Note: you shouldn't need to edit machine.config to enable trace, just web.config. Also the text of the error page mentions that trace is never enabled for retail deployments. Does this happen to be deployed that way?

Comment: I have added the code. I am not sure about the retail deployment. I searched for <deployment retail=true> in the machine.config file. But there is no such code in there. I did not make any changes in that file.

Comment: Does `web.config` or `machine.config` contain `<deployment retail="true"/>` ???

Comment: <deployment retail> would be in web.config not machine.config. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298(VS.80).aspx  Machine.config sets defaults inherited by everybody.

Comment: @modal_dialog here is ScottGu recommending making this setting in `machine.config` as a safeguard against inadvertent deployment of debug enabled code to a PROD environment.  A lot of people read this guy's blog and take actions based on what he says -- just sayin'. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/442448

Comment: @David, sure that's reasonable. The beauty of machine.config is you can setup anything there, but it can also be dangerous to edit because people tend to rely on the defaults. I guess I just think of trace (and debug) as an application-specific setting not something that should have a global default. I'm not saying don't do it, I just never considered doing it myself.

Comment: There is no deployment related code in either files. That's why I am confused. Should I add it to my web.config file? Maybe, the default is true if it is not specified?

Comment: It would have to be specifically that <deployment> tag I think. Can you edit the question to include that text from either/both of the files that have it? Note: in machine.config it will be <section name="deployment" ...etc etc...> just like trace is defined above.

Comment: My machine.config file has this:     <section name="deployment" type="System.Web.Configuration.DeploymentSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowDefinition="MachineOnly"/>

Answer (score 0):

Acccording to this blog post: http://knucklebones.blogspot.com/2010/11/enable-tracing-in-aspnet-mvc.html

You need to add a little extra web.config plumbing for MVC:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace>
      <listeners>
          <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
               type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```